# Lotus Notes: Multiple @MailSend in relation with @DBlookup

Tags: view, lotus-notes, formula

Here is my scenario: There is an app, which notificates some users in X days before 'today'.

These users and the number of days are introduced in a configuration zone. Here is the view which list them: ( btw, there can be a bigger number of days, as many as the admin wants )

```
Days | Persons |
______________
30
      Name1
      Name2
      Name3
60
      Name4
      Name5
```

Before this configuration zone was created, I used only a simple formula in an agent ( which is scheduled to run daily) , something like this: ( there were only 30 days fixed - now the user can set in the configuration zone as many days as he wants )

```
@If(@Date(@Adjust(@Date(@Now);0;0;30;0;0;0)) = @Date(final_date)); 
    (@MailSend("Name1":"Name2":"Name3";"";"";"This document expires in 30 days!";"";"";
[IncludeDoclink]) );
```

I know using `@DBLookup` and `@Dbcolumn` I can get the values from the 2 columns in the view. But how can I create as many  @MailSend functions depending on the size of the number of days established on the configuration zone? Should I create an array with the length = the 'length' of the `@DbColumn` elements from the 1st column?

Also, it is necessarily to create just one agent ( using multiple @MailSend ) or more than one? If there is any chance, I would like doing this in Formula Language, or, if it is more understandable and simpler, in LotusScript.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate difference of days between `@Date(final_date)` and `@Today` and use this as the key for `@DbLookup(... [FAILSILENT])` to get the name's list for `@MailSend`. If the list is empty you don't have to send a mail.

Comment: Thanks. If the returned names from the DbLookup are more than 1, should I use any @Functions or just the field name?

Comment: `@DbLookup`'s result is `@MailSend`'s first parameter - without any further @Function as it is a name list already.

Comment: And for the difference of days: (@Date(final_date)-@Today)/86400 should work, right?

Comment: My conditions for the date fields don't work. I have smth like this:  days := @If(txt_case="";(@Date(date1)-@Today)/86400;
txt_case2="Case2";(@Date(date2)-@Today)/86400;
txt_case3="Case3";(@Date(date3)-@Today)/86400;
@Return(""));
The fields name and the strings are OK, but the result is always null.

Comment: Try to figure out with `@Prompt` where the issue is. Try little peaces of formula first and go forward then.

Comment: I just verified: days := (@Date(date1)-@Today)/86400; and then @Prompt([Ok];"Testing";days); and it is NULL. The problem is here, I guess, I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it in Lotusscript. Much easier, in my opinion.

Use the AllEntries property of the NotesView class to get a NotesDocumentCollection object containing all entries in the view, hen use GetFirstEntry/GetNextExtry to loop through the collection.

Use the ColumnValues property of the NotesViewEntry object to get the first and second column (much faster than actually opening/accessing the NotesDocument object) and then simply mail the user.

It would also be much easier to compare dates. Simply create a NotesDateValue object with todays date, set it to *n* days in the future -- where *n* is the value in ColumnValues(0) -- and compare that with the final date (which you should also put in a column in the view for fast lookup).

I woudl also suggest that you us a >= comparison. If the agent fails to run one day, no notifications will be sent with your code. Then set a flag on the document if the notification was successfully sent, and exclude any documents with that flag from being displayed in the view.

Comment: Thank you, Karl-Henry. I will try to write it also in Lotus Script. Thanks for your tips!